# There is a column named "column" in table "table", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: python, postgresql

so im trying to enter data from a python dictionary into a postgres database using a for loop.Heres the code

```
for value in dic:
    domain_desc = value["domain_desc"]
    commodity_desc = value["commodity_desc"]
    statisticcat_desc = value["statisticcat_desc"]
    agg_level_desc = value["agg_level_desc"]
    country_name = value["country_name"]
    state_name = value["state_name"]
    county_name = value["county_name"]
    unit_desc = value["unit_desc"]
    value1 = value["Value"]
    year_val = value["year"]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO fact_data (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value,year) VALUES (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value1,year_val)")
    cur.commit()
    print("Success!")
```

I keep getting the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Backup/PycharmProjects/gro-app/harvest.py", line 123, in 
>       cur.execute("INSERT INTO fact_data (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value,year) VALUES (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value1,year_val)")
>   psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "domain_desc" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...te_name,county_name,unit_desc,value,year) VALUES (domain_des...
>                                                                ^
>   HINT:  There is a column named "domain_desc" in table "fact_data", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

I have the database and the table in the right place. What is causing this error? I have found a similar question but i dont understand the error and its in a different context
Someone help me understand this

Comment: After the `VALUES` you have to give the actual values and not the column name again.

Comment: Those are Variable names

Comment: Not when written inside a string. Read http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters to see how to pass variables.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks that worked.. I wasnt passing the variables correctly

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to add variables inside values, and use + to concatenate strings:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO fact_data (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value,year) VALUES (" + ', '.join(map(str, (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value1,year_val))) + ")")
```

Consider using map to make strings from your variables, join to join them to a long string.

I'd even suggest you to do it separately, to make it more readable:

```
dict_value = ', '.join(map(str, (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value1,year_val)))

cur.execute("INSERT INTO fact_data (domain_desc,commodity_desc,statisticcat_desc,agg_level_desc,country_name,state_name,county_name,unit_desc,value,year) VALUES (" + dict_value + ")"
```

Comment: This approach is vulnerable to SQL injections, don't do that!

Comment: Depends on where those variables come from. If this dict is being checked before, then it is ok. In general I agree, there is a large security issue in setting variables to DB w/o checking them before, but that was not the question matter.

Comment: Sorry this didnt work, KlausD. Comment in in my question helped